# Android/Java - Removing Substring Starting from last character until a certain character

Tags: java, android, regex, string

Good day. Sorry for the vague title.

I have an Android Application where I have a custom listView, in that custom ListView, I have item names. For example, the list may look like:

1. Item A
2. Sample Item B
3. Sample List Item C
4. Example (Item) D
5. Last (Example) Item E

The user can perform actions and the list updates to something like:

1. Item A (UNIT OF FACTOR)
2. Sample Item B
3. Sample List Item C
4. Example (Item) D
5. Last (Example) Item (E)

As you can see, the first item was appended to based on the user input. I want to remove this appended user input (space before the parenthesis and parenthesis included)  This appended user input varies in length so I can't do `String item = item.replace(item.substring((str.length()-lengthOfInput),""));`

I can't do substring deletion for anything enclosed with parenthesis because of items 4 and 5 where there are strings enclosed in parenthesis aside from the future user input that will be enclosed with parenthesis.

The solution I'm thinking of right now is to check the last character of the item, if it's a `)`, I then traverse the string backwards until I hit a `(`, then check if that substring contains `OF`.

I've checked my database of Items, and all items ending with a substring enclosed in parenthesis do not contain the pattern `UNIT OF FACTOR`, making my solution in mind viable.

Now, my question is, is there a short hand solution for this? I know I can do a for loop to traverse the String from the last position, a `)` in some cases, and traverse backwards until I hit `(`. After hitting the first `(`, I have my substring. I can then check that substring if it contains `OF`, if so, I trim it, else, it's not the string I want to remove.

Is there a shorter version on how to do this? Sorry if I'm asking for help when I already have a viable solution at hand. I'm asking for help because I don't want to code a long solution when a shorter one is available. Also, I formulated the solution above as I was typing this question in - apologies about that.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a very basic regex of the form

```
\\([^)]*OF[^)]*\\
```

OR

Using positive look ahead as

```
\\([^)]*(?=OF).*\\)
```

For example

```
String str = "Item A (UNIT OF FACTOR)", str1= "Item A (B)";;
str =   str.replaceAll("\\([^)]*OF[^)]*\\)", "");
str1 =  str1.replaceAll("\\([^)]*OF[^)]*\\)", ""); 
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(str1);


str = "Item A (UNIT OF FACTOR)";
str1 = "Item A (B)";
str =   str.replaceAll("\\([^)]*(?=OF).*\\)", ""); // Using postive look ahead
str1 =  str1.replaceAll("\\([^)]*(?=OF).*\\)", ""); // Using postive look ahead
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(str1);
```

will give an output

```
Item A 
Item A (B)
Item A 
Item A (B)
```

Comment: That won't work properly since if the String is `Item (b)`, the output would be `Item` instead of `Item (b)`. I only want to remove the substring inside the parenthesis if it contains "OF".

Comment: @Razgriz I have edited the answer to take care of that . Hope it helps you

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the difference between the simple form and the positive look ahead?

Comment: @Razgriz You are welcome :). Here there is no difference between the two. but at times there are overheads associated with each method.